# SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry

Tags: node.js, postgresql, azure, ssl, tls1.2

I use azure postgres, so when I disable SSL it works fine but I want SSL connection enabled and when I enable from azure
and then when I start my application ERROR: `SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry` This error occurs multiple time

where in docs of azure
[Azure Docs for SSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-ssl-connection-security#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20Azure%20portal,the%20SSL%20enforce%20status%20indicator)
.
here is my connection string

```
connection: {
        database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE || 'postgres',
        port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT || 5432,
        user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER || 'my@-username',
        host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST || 'postgres.db.postgres.database.azure.com',
        password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD || 'postpass',
        sslmode: 'require',
        }
```

as per azure docs i specify that `sslmode:require` but its not working
is anyone face the same error and got the solution then let me know, I stuck into this error from last 5 days.

Comment: Try `ssl: true` instead of `sslmode: 'require'`

Comment: Try to connect with a different client (like `psql`) and see if you get the same error.

Comment: You need to provide your ssl cert.

Comment: @kirtan DO you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following steps

1. Download the [SSL certificate](https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem). For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-ssl-connection-security#applications-that-require-certificate-verification-for-tls-connectivity)
2. Code

```
const pg = require("pg");
const fs = require("fs");
const config = {
  host: "<>.postgres.database.azure.com",
  user: "<>",
  password: "<>",
  database: "postgres",
  port: 5432,
  ssl: {
    cert: fs.readFileSync("<the cert path>"),
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
  },
};

const client = new pg.Client(config);

client.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  else {
    console.log("success");
  }
});
const query = "SELECT * FROM inventory;";

client
  .query(query)
  .then((res) => {
    const rows = res.rows;
    console.log(`Read: ${JSON.stringify(rows)}`);
    process.exit();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

[image]